# Does the equation $\varphi(n)=\sigma(m)$ have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The question is in the title. It was asked by Paul Erdős, e.g. as part of Section 9 in this [paper](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eyoshi/resenhas/abstracts/Erdos.pdf).

Comment: The question would be slightly more useful with a bit more information: Page 6, problem 9 of SOME OF ..., in which journal or book? ("Das Kapital de K. Marx" seems to be the wrong answer.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ime.usp.br/~yoshi/resenhas/abstracts/Erdos.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiL486xht7yAhX6HbkGHf4sCpYQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1RjCFcrlvhmsQf4hs0T5Fs

Comment: Download in PDF

Comment: @RolandBacher Meanwhile, in "Das Kapital", page 6, problem 9:

$$\text{Is it true that for infinitely many pairs }\phi(n)={\huge\color{red}{☭}} =\sigma(m)$$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this was proved by [Ford, Luca and Pomerance](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eford/wwwpapers/phi=sig.pdf) in 2010 (paper in Bulletin of the London Math. Soc.).

Comment: The  main theorem in that paper would be later improved by Professor M. Z. Garaev in his paper "On the number of common values of arithmetic functions φ and σ below x" (Moscow Journal of Combinatorics and Number Theory, vol. 1 (2011), no. 3, pp. 42-49): http://mjcnt.phystech.edu/en/article.php?id=24